# Replacing a word by synonyms in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary, plagiarism-detection

I was going through this [plagiarism detector](http://blog.moertel.com/articles/2011/06/16/writing-a-simple-plagiarism-detector-in-haskell) and trying to write a program in Haskell which will read a file and replace some of its words with synonyms. Is there any dictionary available for this purpose in Haskell?

Also, if you have any input regarding algorithm or any other input relevant for this problem, like how to avoid changing the context of a statement by replacing a word by its synonyms, then please post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any dictionary available for this purpose in Haskell?

I would imagine that what you are looking for is a plain text file, something like this:

```
word1: word1synonym1, word1synonym2, ...
word2: word2synonym1, ...
...
```

In which case it wouldn't really be Haskell-specific. I'm unaware of any free text-file thesauruses like this, though I imagine if you dig around [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) you would probably find one.

> how to avoid changing the context of a statement by replacing a word by its synonyms

This is very hard for a computer to do, afaik. I would suggest not expending much effort working on this aspect of it.

> any input regarding algorithm

You may find the concept of [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) useful for this problem. See [Approximate string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) and [Wagner-Fischer algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%E2%80%93Fischer_algorithm).